# Breakpoint set but not yet bound in Visual Studio Code for a dockerized node process

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the debugger in Visual Studio Code on a macOS Catalina for a node app. I created a very simple example to illustrate my case.

**index.js**

```
require('http').createServer( (request, response) => {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
  response.end('Hello World\n');
  response.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.14.0-alpine 
COPY . /src
CMD ["node","--inspect=0.0.0.0", "src/index.js"]
```

I build the Dockerfile

```
docker build . -t debugtest
```

and then run it

```
 docker run -p 3000:3000 -p 9229:9229 debugtest
```

I can access http://localhost:3000/.

I set a breakpoint in index.js.

[image]
Then setup a debugger target in visual studio code

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 9229,
    "skipFiles": [
      "<node_internals>/**"
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Now when I start the debugger in visual code the red dot of the breakpoint disappears and "Breakpoint set but not yet bound" appears.

[image]

I have seen that question in various spots but none of the solutions worked. When I run the node process outside of docker `node --inspect index.js` it works without a hitch.

I am using version 1.41.1 of visual studio code and docker 2.1.0.5.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out I was omitting the `remoteRoot` attribute in `launch.json`. The below works.

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",        
    "port": 9229,
    "remoteRoot": "/src/",
    "skipFiles": [
      "<node_internals>/**"
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This just saved my day! I used the "default" `launch.json`, the one that gets created when you select "Attach to Docker". That has a `remoteRoot` property but it points to `/usr/src/app` which is not where I put my application code inside the container so just changing it to where my code lives in the container fixed this issue.

Comment: Saved me also, so I also didn't know that `remoteRoot` was the path to the app code inside the container which I got from my `Dockerfile`